set multiple validator patterns for a single textbox based on user input
Here is the formcontrol I am using. If the user enters Country US i need to set the validator as shown below (min length 5 max length 12)
lblzip1 = new FormControl('', Validators.compose([
        Validators.required,
        this.noWhitespaceValidator,
        Validators.pattern('^[a-zA-Z0-9- ]{5,15}$')
    ]));

IF the user enters any other country other than US I need to set the validator as shown below (min length 1, mx length 15)
lblzip1 = new FormControl('', Validators.compose([
        Validators.required,
        this.noWhitespaceValidator,
        Validators.pattern('^[a-zA-Z0-9- ]{1,15}$')
    ]));

Can you please let me know how do we do this in angular?

May be you can use a customer Validotor and after call him in your form.
The validator will adjust the validation rules in base on your country selection.
This is a sample of code:
Custom Validator


import { AbstractControl, ValidationErrors, ValidatorFn } from '@angular/forms';

export function zipCodeValidator(country: string): ValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
    if (!control.value) {
      return null;
    }

    const value = control.value.trim();

   
    const countryValidationRules = {
      'US': { minLength: 5, maxLength: 12, pattern: /^[a-zA-Z0-9- ]{5,12}$/ },
      'default': { minLength: 1, maxLength: 15, pattern: /^[a-zA-Z0-9- ]{1,15}$/ }
    };

    
    const rules = countryValidationRules[country] || countryValidationRules['default'];

    
    if (value.length < rules.minLength || value.length > rules.maxLength) {
      return { length: true };
    }

   
    if (!rules.pattern.test(value)) {
      return { pattern: true };
    }

    
    return null;
  };
}




That's NOT work if "country" is an input. When you define a FormControl with a validator, const country='US'; control=new FormControl('',customValidator(country)) the validator function "make inmutable" the value of the variable. The solution is make a customValidator that involve the two FormControls, see e.g. SO related to mannage two FormControls.
